# How to Selectively choose rows in a key in map reduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have the following csv files with 5 columns and many rows. But I'm showing only first 6 rows.

```
Date,Food,Vitamin,Protein,NumStudents
01/01/17, Pasta, A, Yes, 560
01/01/17, Pizza, A, Yes, 730
01/01/17, Burrito, C, Yes, 240
02/01/17, Pizza, A, Yes, 340
02/01/17, Pasta, B, Yes, 450
02/01/17, Beef, B, Yes, 450
```

Now I want to find the sum of NumStudents on a particular day who had only Pizza and Pasta.

In essence for `01/01/17` I only have to sum NumStudents for Pizza and Pasta but not Burrito.

Expected Output

```
01/01/17 1290
02/01/17 790
```

Output I'm getting

```
01/01/17 1530
02/01/17 1240
```

In my code I'm able to sum NumStudents for all 3 types of food but don't know how to selectively exclude some type of food from my composite key in mapper. Any idea how should I go about it?

Below is my code

```
public class GroupMR {

    public static class GroupMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, DateYear, IntWritable> {




        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            String line = value.toString();
            String[] keyvalue = line.split(",");
            monyeartext.set(new Text(keyvalue[0]));

            //populat.set(Integer.parseInt(keyvalue[5]));
            termText.set(keyvalue[1]);
            try {
                numpass.set(Integer.parseInt(keyvalue[4]));
            }catch (NumberFormatException e){
                System.out.println("not a number"); 
            } 
            DateYear monyear = new DateYear(monyeartext, termText);
            context.write(monyear, numpass);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

String[] keyvalue = line.split(",");

```
Please add a filter after this line 

if(!(keyvalue[2].equals("Pasta") ||keyvalue[2].equals("Pizza")) ){
  // If the food item is not pizza or pasta then  return
  return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked!! I have one more issue right now my result is sorted by month. How can I sort it by year instead of month so that it outputs values year by year?

Comment: There is a better way of saying thanks and that is upvoting :D . 

1. The output is being sorted in ASCII collating sequence. and not month (its seems like its month)
2. For immediate results just change the date format in the MAPPER. to YYYY/MM/DD . right now its DD/MM/YYYY

Comment: I didn't get what you mean. Can you please explain a bit more as to how should I change the format in mapper?

Comment: parse the date keyvalue[0]  and form a new string with format YYYY/MM/DD

Answer (score 0):

I have reduced the code ,I have picked only month and date  and it is sorted based on year.

```
public class GroupMR {

public static class GroupMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {

    Text numpass = null;
    Text monyeartext = null;

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String line = value.toString();
        String[] keyvalue = line.split(",");
        String[] monyeartext1 = keyvalue[0].split("/");
        monyeartext = new Text(monyeartext1[2] + "/" +monyeartext1[0] );
        numpass = new Text(keyvalue[1] + "-" + keyvalue[4]);
        context.write(monyeartext, numpass);

    }
}

public static class GroupReducer extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        boolean doesExist = false;
        int sum = 0;           
        for (Text val : values) {
            String[] val2 = val.toString().split("-");
            if (val2[0].equals("Pizza") || val2[0].equals("Pasta") ){
                sum += Integer.parseInt(val2[1]);
            }
        }
        context.write(key, new IntWritable(sum));
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    String[] otherArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args).getRemainingArgs();
    if (otherArgs.length < 2) {
        System.err.println("Usage: wordcount <in> [<in>...] <out>");
        System.exit(2);
    }
    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "GroupMR");
    job.setJarByClass(GroupMR.class);
    job.setMapperClass(GroupMapper.class);

    job.setReducerClass(GroupReducer.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    //for (int i = 0; i < otherArgs.length - 1; ++i) {
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[0]));
   // }

    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[1]));
    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
}
```

}